# Cangjie reference

Tags: vocabulary, characters, cantonese

I'm currently starting to learn to use a cangjie keyboard for typing Chinese (倉頡) and I'm struggling to find the combinations for characters. I would like a resource where I can use my slower handwriting recognition keyboard to type in a character and it'll return the correct key combination.

Before you suggest for me to use a zhuyin keyboard or other, I wasn't born in Hong Kong / China, and neither have I had the adequate education to know enough Chinese, as I was taught it by my parents.

Comment: I'm not sure of an app that is solely for converting a character to its Cangjie inputs, but there are a few online resources like [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%A0%A1#Translingual) that will display Cangjie decompositions. There are a few Wiktionary smartphone apps these days, so if you get one of those that should do the trick.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cangjie_input_method

Comment: But I still want to suggest you to use other input method, cuz cangjie is harder to learn than other methods. If you like methods based on stroke, try 五笔, or if you like methods based on pronunciation, try pinyin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

至少有兩種資源：網站和對照表

## 五個網站資源

(1) [漢文庫典](http://hanculture.com/dic/)

> 漢文庫典的資料庫及字詞、成語等典籍，係以【朱邦復工作室】所發展的倉頡系統製作、轉換。

朱邦復是倉頡輸入法的發明人。這像是官方最新的版本。

[image]

(2) [馬來西亞 倉頡之友](http://www.chinesecj.com/cj5dict/index.php)

以第五代倉頡碼為主，有時會有第三代的編碼。

[image]

(3) [維基詞典](https://zh.wiktionary.org/wiki/)

這似乎是第三代的編碼。有時會有第五代的編碼。

[image]
[image]
[image]

(4) [汉典](http://www.zdic.net/)

[image]

(5) [国学大师](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/zidian/)

[image]

## 六個對照表資源

輸入法的對照表可以下載並存放在自己的電腦中，離線查詢。但是這些對照表都是複製來複製去的，有些又是開發者自己修改的，所以錯誤的機率較高。

這些對照表可以去其原始碼庫下載。

(1) [馬來西亞 倉頡之友 倉頡平台2012](http://www.chinesecj.com/forum/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=2596&extra=page%3D1)

下載外掛版本： CJSYS-20110919.zip

(2) [ibus](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ibus/downloads?page=9)

直接下載連結： [ibus-table-cangjie-1.2.0.20100305.tar.gz](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/ibus/ibus-table-cangjie-1.2.0.20100305.tar.gz)

(3) [scim](https://sourceforge.net/projects/scim/files/scim-tables/0.5.14/)

直接下載連結： [scim-tables-0.5.14.1.tar.gz](https://sourceforge.net/projects/scim/files/scim-tables/0.5.14/scim-tables-0.5.14.1.tar.gz/download)

(4) [fcitx](https://download.fcitx-im.org/fcitx-table-extra/)

直接下載連結： [fcitx-table-extra-0.3.8.tar.xz](https://download.fcitx-im.org/fcitx-table-extra/fcitx-table-extra-0.3.8.tar.xz)

(5) [gcin](http://hyperrate.com/gcin-source/)

直接下載連結： [gcin-2.8.5.tar.xz](http://hyperrate.com/gcin-source/gcin-2.8.5.tar.xz)

(6) [hime](https://github.com/hime-ime/hime/tree/master/data)

直接下載連結： [cj5.cin](https://github.com/hime-ime/hime/blob/master/data/cj5.cin)

Comment: Thanks! Are you from HK? It is scarce that I see someone type in Traditional Chinese because most come from China, or learn the Chinese from China

Comment: @VortexYT If it was helpful please up vote it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already have a good handwriting tool, but if there's a problem with it, https://chineseinput.net/handwriting.html can also be used for handwriting input.

I've used zdic from the previous answer and think it's a great resource. However, sites like that can also be quite slow to load and use a lot of memory.

http://dict.tw/ can be loaded quickly and can return cangjie codes (for versions 3 and 5) without much time or memory usage.

Sample output from http://dict.tw/ with Cangjie codes pointed out :

```
 贏
 【注音】 ㄧㄥˊ 〔U/6〕
 【大易】 立女口點 〔KLO.〕
 【大易】 立女點 〔KL.〕
 【倉頡】 卜口月月弓 〔YRBBN〕    <---Cangjie 3
 【倉頡五代】 卜弓月山金 〔YNBUC〕 <---Cangjie 5
 【行列30】 6⇡7⇡7⇣6- 〔YUMH〕
 【行列30】 6⇡7⇡7⇣4- 〔YUMF〕
 【行列30】 6⇡7⇡7⇣1⇣ 〔YUMZ〕
 【四角號碼】 0021
 【電報碼】 6366
 【大五碼】 C4 B9
 ◄ ►
From: MDBG CC-CEDICT Chinese-English Dictionary 漢英字典

 贏 [ㄧㄥˊ; ying2]
 to beat
 to win
 to profit
 ◄ ►
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23870)

Comment: The user asked for resources. 
Online tools are resources accessed via links.

I have no idea what you mean when you say "...the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference"? Is that a canned response, because it doesn't seem to make sense in this case? Please explain what you mean?

Comment: yes, it was a canned response. Actually you are right, it doesn't make a lot of sense here, since the question is actually asking for resources. I reviewed the post hastily, sorry for that. That notwithstanding; posting answers that only contain links (and little else) is discouraged, because if the link breaks, there's basically nothing else left. You could add some more explanation e.g. why you think that resource is useful, etc

Comment: No worries. And thanks, I think I understand your point. The more details, the better and more helpful a post can be. I've tried to add some additional details above and can tweak if further if you see something I didn't. BTW, do you know how to highlight or bold within a block quote?

Comment: mmm, I think you can’t have extra markdown in a block quote, only in regular quote (the one with leading `>`)

Comment: I see, thanks. I was able to use "<---" instead. :)